# Parse date string with different date format

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to know how to parse date strings that could have different date format.

For now I do the following to parse my date strings:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").parse;
```

How to specify multiple date format to my `parseDate` function?

Comment: You can't. You need something that tells you what format to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Date('YOUR DATE STRING')`

Also checkout [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/),
You can use `moment('YOUR DATE STRING')`

`moment` will try to interpret the String according to standard formats, if not it will fall back to Javascript's native `Date()` constructor.

This should work for standard ISO format or a variety of commonly seen date formats. Obviously it is not magic and will not understand all possible permutations of YYYY MM and DD

Comment: This really is leaving things to chance. Is 1/2/2016 a date for January 2 or 1 February? How about 08/09/02? You should **always** pass the string format to the parser.

Comment: Although the question is old... i stumbled upon this today. Momentjs's parser actually supports a specific array of formats that will be tried in the provided order. So if you know the possible formats momentjs can be used as a safe and graceful way to comply to the requirement.